# python tkinter: displays only a portion of an image

Tags: python, image, tkinter

This only displays the bottom right corner of my image.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, titl, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        self.create_widgets()
        self.master.title(titl)

    def create_widgets(self):

        image_file = 'sample.jpg'
        image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_file))
        w = image1.width()
        h = image1.height() 
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=w+5, height=h+5)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=image1)
        self.canvas.image = image1

app = Application('Image')

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: see e.g. for tkinter+PIL example http://code.activestate.com/recipes/521918-pil-and-tkinter-to-display-images/

Comment: Why would label work, but not canvas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the anchor to `NW` (NorthWest) because its value is `CENTER` by default, which as the name suggests centers the image on the given coordinates:

```
self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=image1, anchor=NW)
```

Or you can change that later if you keep the image id:

```
self.idImage = self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=image1)
...
self.canvas.itemconfig(self.idImage, anchor=NW)
```

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method